# How can I withdraw funds from an escrow contract in web3@1.0.0?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, contract-invocation

I deposited ETH into a simple [contract](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/contractz/blob/master/contracts/Escrow.sol), and I want to get it back. I have this function:

```
function refundBalance() public onlyOwner {
    uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
    msg.sender.transfer(balance);
    emit LogReturnedFunds(msg.sender, balance);
}
```

I call it via node and web3@1.0.0-beta.35 in the terminal:

```
contract.methods.refundBalance().call().then(console.log)
```

Alas, I only get this empty response: `Result {}` and no state update on Ropsten. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
`contract.methods.refundBalance().send().then(console.log)`.
```

`call` is used for functions that [do not change the state](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call). They're decared as `view` or `pure`. However, `refundBalance()` [does change the state](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send). Therefore, use `send`